# Adobe AIR Security Error loading .swf with RSS

Tags: apache-flex, security, air, adobe

I'm trying to load an swf file using SWFLoader in Adobe AIR app. The problem is that after the swf loads, Adobe AIR shows me the following error. I know that this swf tries to download an RSS file from the web.

> SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///xfile.swf cannot access Internet

How can i fix it? Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AIR SWFs that are loaded from outside of the contents of the AIR file get put into a sandbox.  You need to include the SWF file you are loading in your AIR file.  If that is not possible then you will need to make sure that the loaded SWF doesn't try to get outside the sandbox.  Read more about the AIR sandbox:

- [Introducing the Adobe AIR security model](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/introduction_to_air_security.html)
- [AIR Security - Sandboxes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f05.html)