# Loaded .swf in Adobe AIR cannot find its media files

Tags: javascript, flash, air, swfobject

I'm developing an Adobe AIR javascript application which loads an .swf file exported from InDesign (interactive book). That .swf has a "MySWF_Resources" directory with a sample .flv video.

The problem is, when I load that .swf into my AIR application using SWFobject it loses the ability to load its assets - somehow the paths are incorrect when run inside AIR environment. The same .swf file executed in a browser properly loads the video from "MySWF_Resources" directory.

Is it possible to somehow force the working directory in which .swf should look for the files? AIR breaks somehow relative paths for included .swfs.

Comment: I think this simiar answer on Stackoverflow should help you - [previous question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489137/adobe-air-security-error-loading-swf-with-rss

Comment: I don't think it's the issue with sandboxes. The .swf itself loads fine from app-storage:/. Also the error seems to affect only .flv media files when I try to load them from said .swf. A different .swf can load .mp3 files just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you would include FLV / movie files via SWF in an air application. You need to use the absolute path of the FLV file since Flash does not know the Air app:/ structure. You can do the following:

1. Include AIRAliases.js (located in air sdk package)
2. Include jPlayer ([LINK](http://www.jplayer.org))
3. Add air event listener for invocation ([LINK](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-7ffc))
4. Save the current directory to a variable/object in javascript
5. Reverse slashes of location ( `myVar.replace(/\\/g,"/")` )
6. Pass in the location + file.flv to jPlayer object

Using jPlayer saves a number of steps, but if you would like to do it via standard SWF you need to create the embed/object via javascript and pass in a flashvars for the location of the FLV file. You then have the flashvars set the content source in the SWF via ActionScript ([LINK](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)).